# Como carregar a aplicação conforme o id de usuário?

Tags: android

No meu aplicativo tem um cadastro de usuários. Cada usuário possui um nome e email, gostaria que quando iniciasse o aplicativo ele guardasse o id do usuário padrão (ou recarregasse o aplicativo quando eu trocasse o usuário) pois eu iria buscar as informações do banco de dados conforme a chave `id_usuario` e listar a partir desse atributo. Um exemplo:

[image: Tela principal]

E nas outras telas também, teria como eu guardar esse usuário e usar nas telas que tenho de listagem de despesa/receita e inserção de despesa/receita?

Me alertaram sobre um tal de *Singleton*, gostaria de ver se é possível também usá-lo.

Comment: onde voce esta guardando esses utilizadores? no celular ou na cloud?

Comment: no celular mesmo, fiz uma table e guardo lá, bem simples mesmo. @dariodm

Comment: certro deixa responder!

Comment: deixa quem responder? @dariodm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara se vc esta guardando o usuario em uma tabela.
quando vc iniciar o app pegue seu usuario na tabela, e o coloca no Application.
Assim de qualquer tela vc consegue acessar seu usuario.

Segue o exemplo

**no manifest**

```
<application
        android:name="pacote.MyApplication"
```

**Classe Application**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private User user;
...gets sets
```

**sua Actv principal**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyApplication application;
private User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

application = (MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext();

user = //pego o user em seu db sqlite
application.setUser(user); // set o user no seu application
//agora pode usar o objeto que e esta no Apllication
// Ex: application.getUser().getNome;
```

**usando em outra Actv**

```
public class OutraActivity extends Activity {
private MyApplication application;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_outra_tela);

application = (MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext();
//use o objeto do Application
application.getUser().getNome;
```

espero ter ajudado no seu conhecimento...e em seu app...

valew

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! E quando eu quiser trocar de usuário? eu tenho uma opção na tela principal de trocar usuário, nele eu abro um dialog com um spinner que me dá os nomes dos users, como faço pra recarregar o app com o usuário que eu acabei de escolher? @FlipNovid

Comment: set o usuario do Application no seu dialog, com o click do spinner, mais ai vc precisa colocar um callback para ao clicar mudar na activity. Acho, não é certeza, que quando se abre um dialog e volta pra Actv ela na entra o onresume, mais se entra no on renume da Actv vc seta nele os componentes com os atributos do seu novo user user. OK... valew

Comment: Estou tentando usar o application = (MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext(); em uma classe sqliteopenhelper e não tenho esse getapplicationcontext... como devo prosseguir?

Comment: Vc esta em uma Actv, Frag ou FragActv? Certeza que nao pulou nenhum passo... ? @Allan Chrystian

Comment: 'application = ((MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext());' tente assim